# In Linux I got Too many open files issue

Tags: linux

In Linux I got Too many open files issue, Then we increase the soft file limit and hard file limit from 1024 to 65355 and still getting same issue

```
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2129)
    at com.boomi.util.FileUtil.createTempFile(FileUtil.java:901)
    at com.boomi.util.FileUtil.createTempDirectory(FileUtil.java:880)
    at com.boomi.util.FileUtil.createTempDirectory(FileUtil.java:862)
    at com.boomi.transform.data.DataNodeCache.createStorageLocation(DataNodeCache.java:352)
    at com.boomi.store.db.BigMap.getDb(BigMap.java:592)
    ... 84 more
Nov 2, 2022 8:46:02 AM AEDT WARNING [com.boomi.util.LogUtil doLog] Failed purging bigmap cache (2)
java.sql.SQLException: Failed creating storage location
    at com.boomi.store.db.BigMap.getDb(BigMap.java:594)
    at com.boomi.transform.data.DataNodeCache.store(DataNodeCache.java:270)
    at com.boomi.transform.data.DataNodeCache.store(DataNodeCache.java:29)
    at com.boomi.store.db.BigMap$NewRef.discard(BigMap.java:735)
    at com.boomi.store.db.BigMap.trimCache(BigMap.java:393)
    at com.boomi.store.db.BigMap.reduceMemoryIfNecessary(BigMap.java:583)
    at com.boomi.store.db.BigMap.put(BigMap.java:361)
    at com.boomi.store.db.BigMap.put(BigMap.java:280)
```

Comment: Did you logout, login and restart the app?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unless it is a special app that actually needs to have so many files open, this is normally the indication that the app is not closing the files after use and/or is re-opening the files again and again. That is a bug that must be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The limits that you have changed are for the user and session.

Is strongly recommended to logout and restart the app. On the other hand, have you modified the limits for the OS? Have you tried (apart from performing an logout, login and a restart of the app/script) performing the following?

Edit */etc/sysctl.conf* and add:

**fs.file-max = 999999**

Save changes and perform the command

```
sysctl -p
```

Last, but not least, you would have to restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

When the “Too Many Open Files” error message is written to the logs, it indicates that all available file handles for the process have been used (this includes sockets as well).

“Too many open files“ errors happen when a process needs to open more files than it is allowed by the operating system. This number is controlled by the maximum number of file descriptors the process has.

There are 3 ways you can cross-check.

1. Check Too many open files in SYSTEM Wide settings in Linux

   To see the settings for maximum open files for the OS level, use the following command:

   ```
   # cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
   ```
2. Check Too many open files Per USER Settings in Linux

   We can see the setting for maximum open files for a user, as root issue the following commands:

   ```
   # su – <user>
   $ ulimit -n
   ```

   The default setting for this is usually 1024.
3. Check Too many open files in systemd service on Linux

   If we start a instance as a systemd service, we can specify limits within the `[Service]` section of its service file. The service file has a location like `/etc/systemd/system/<process-name>.service`.